# how does hibernate sessionfactory manage session?

Tags: hibernate, session, connection, sessionfactory

I have just got the relationship between Hibernate Session and Connection. 
But now, I get another question: how does hibernate sessionfactory manage session?
In the following code segment: save() method of a DAO class:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
   Transaction tx=null;
   tx=session.beginTransaction(); 
   session.save(transientInstance);
   session.flush();
   tx.commit();
```

When we call `sessionFactory.openSession()` , it will create a new session attached to the current thread (through the ThreadLocal), this session is also attached to a JDBC connection, 
But, as you can see, we don't need to close the session (session.close()), neither the connection. 
So, what is the lifecycle of a Hibernate session, in what circumstances it will be closed? automatically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend the `getCurrentSession` method because only with this method you have the possibility to be sure that the session will be closed from hibernate

[Configuration J2EE Current Session.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-j2ee-currentsession)

If you use the `openSession` method, you must close the sessions by yourself.
After i begin to work with hibernate i thought it does'n matter which method I use because all session will be closed automatically... i was wrong.
I had discovered with the SessionStatistics from hibernate
[SessionStatistics](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/stat/SessionStatistics.html)
that the open session was already opened and never closed.
After i changed all calls to `getCurrentSession` and `impl`. the Session-per-request pattern opened session will be closed after work.

[Transactions Basics](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-apptx).

Comment: Thank to Zelldon, I will figure it out with the given references.