# Managing the current Hibernate session from static factory

Tags: java, hibernate, session

Ive built a j2ee app with hibernate and I had a quick question on managing the session object.

In my repositories, I get access to the Hibernate session from a static SessionFactory

```
private static SessionFactory factory;
public static Session getSession(){
   return factory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

From my research, it's good to reuse the SessionFactory, but do I need to dispose the session or close it when the http session terminates?

I have the session context configured to "thread"

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Comment: It depends, for starters have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15613989/3080094)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but can you please elaborate on what you mean by "it depends"? In my case I'm not calling openSession(). I'm also not using JMX

Comment: It is complex to say the least: [current session architecture](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch02.html#architecture-current-session) - relevant javadocs for [ThreadLocalSessionContext](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/internal/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html), 
[session per request](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#session-per-request) and [transactions with JTA](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html#transactions-demarcation-jta). Yes, it is confusing.